# list-style: none alters layout

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble formatting unordered list in CSS.

Below is a sample code snippet:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-2 box text-content">
    <ul class="ul-abilities">
        <li>
        <span class="ability-title">C++</span>
            <div class="ability-score-container">
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <span class="ability-title">Java</span>
            <div class="ability-score-container">
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I apply `list-style: none` inside the CSS selector - `.ul-abilities li`, the order of `li` items gets lopsided. I don't know what I need to do to fix this.

CSS snippet:

```
.ul-abilities li {
    list-style: none; /*--- Troublesome line ---*/
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.ability-title {
    float: left;
    color: #000;
}

.ability-score-container { float: right; }

.ability-score { color: #005fee; }
```

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for your code?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear your floats

```
.ul-abilities li:after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q05d41dy/

Comment: Pleasure :). Check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ I made a clear fix on that specific element but you can make a class that you can put on the parent element (This case the `ul`) and it will clear the floats for you

Answer (score 0):

try below property and check

```
 .ul-abilities li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 5px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `list-style-type: none;` to the `<ul>` tag and not the `<li>`
Remove the `float: left:`

```css
.ul-abilities {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.ul-abilities li {
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.ability-title {
    color: #000;
}

.ability-score-container { float: right; }

.ability-score { color: #005fee; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-2 box text-content">
    <ul class="ul-abilities">
        <li>
        <span class="ability-title">C++</span>
            <div class="ability-score-container">
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star">*</i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star">*</i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star">*</i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star">*</i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star">*</i></span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <span class="ability-title">Java</span>
            <div class="ability-score-container">
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star">*</i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star">*</i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star">*</i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star">*</i></span>
                <span class="ability-score"><i class="fas fa-star">*</i></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the float I think.

```
.ul-abilities li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    clear: both;
}
```